# Rails inserting of a row into table not successfully happening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysqli

I'm trying to add into `timmings` table but record `Timming.where(:in => in)` is not getting other values are it store as expected it returns `t.in` as `nil` somebody please tell me why this occurs.

This is my schema for table:

```
create_table "timmings", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
  t.string "in"
  t.integer "bus_type"
  t.bigint "provider_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer "route_id"
  t.index ["provider_id"], name: "index_timmings_on_provider_id"
end
```

Rails Console:

```
t = Timming.new
=> #<Timming:0x00558be5e2c108 id: nil, in: nil, bus_type: nil, provider_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, route_id: nil>

[250] pry(main)> t.in = Time.now.to_s
[251] pry(main)> t.provider_id = 1
=> 1
[252] pry(main)> t.route_id = 1
=> 1
[253] pry(main)> t.save
(0.4ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Provider Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `providers`.* FROM `providers` WHERE `providers`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Route Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `routes`.* FROM `routes` WHERE `routes`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `timmings` (`provider_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `route_id`) VALUES (1, '2017-07-29 08:06:46', '2017-07-29 08:06:46', 1)
(0.3ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> true
```

Now when I print `t`:

```
id: 18,
in: nil,
bus_type: nil,
provider_id: 1,
created_at: Sat, 29 Jul 2017 08:06:46 UTC +00:00,
updated_at: Sat, 29 Jul 2017 08:06:46 UTC +00:00,
route_id: 1>
```

Can anyone tell me whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

As you mentioned that you have used `attr_accessor` of the same name so what is it first of all? `attr_accessor` is used to define an attribute for object of Model which is not mapped with any column in database. `attr_accessor` creates two methods i.e. getter method and setter method. So in your case Rails defined these:

```
# getter
def in
  @in
end

# setter
def in=(val)
  @in = val
end
```

So whenever you did `t.in = Time.now.to_s` it was assigned to `@in` instead of saving in the database. So that is why you were not able to save the value in database.

**Previous Answer (didn't help the OP):**

Your column is named `in` which is a reserved keyword in MySQL so rename the column to something else and then try it, it should work.

**Source:** [MySQL Reserved Keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Comment: i renamed that coulmn but still couldn't after some searching i have defined attr_accessor :in[later i changed that..] i removed that line from ma model and i can able to write to that element but still confused what it gone wrong with accessor

Comment: @AniketKudale I have updated my answer so you may understand why you were not able to save the value in database.